# system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) error while writing ES6 code in plunker

Tags: javascript, plunker

I'm getting my feet wet with ES6. i'm using plunker. I've got traceur and systemjs loaded. But i'm getting the foll errors:

```
GET https://traceur-compiler.googlecode.com/git/bin/traceur.js 404 ()
VM490 system.js:4 GET https://run.plnkr.co/nouZKWksqlQWsCPz/traceur 404 ()G @ VM490 system.js:4(anonymous function) @ VM490 system.js:4(anonymous function) @ VM490 system.js:4(anonymous function) @ VM490 system.js:5(anonymous function) @ VM490 system.js:5(anonymous function) @ VM490 system.js:5(anonymous function) @ VM490 system.js:5(anonymous function) @ VM490 system.js:5(anonymous function) @ VM490 system.js:5(anonymous function) @ VM490 system.js:4
system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404) loading https://run.plnkr.co/nouZKWksqlQWsCPz/traceur(…)
```

The following is the plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/IOn58GkbGmaZrluLiB3B?p=preview

Can you please help me identify what i could be missing here.

Thanks

Comment: The file `traceur.js` can not be found, hence the `404` status code. Check the url.

Comment: i've got the correct url but it doesnt work: https://traceur-compiler.googlecode.com/git/bin/traceur.js

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue but I resolved it by adding traceur-runtime and traceur-compiler to plunk.

Here is the working Plunk:

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/P0QV925JtInZYIqRXiW3][1]
```